# "data exception: string data, right truncation" on INSERT with prepared statement

Tags: jdbc, parameters, prepared-statement, ucanaccess

When attempting to execute a preparedStatement with parameters in this code

```
public void Insert(String TreeType, String LastWatered, String PlantDate) {
    try {
        String G = "INSERT INTO Trees (TreeType, LastWatered, PlantDate) VALUES 
(?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(G);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, TreeType);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, LastWatered);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, PlantDate);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TreeArr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

I get this error

```
    Sep 09, 2018 2:15:51 AM pat.ConnectDb Insert
    SEVERE: null
    net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 data exception: 
    string data, right truncation;  table: TREES column: TREETYPE
    at 
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:269)
    at pat.ConnectDb.Insert(ConnectDb.java:41)
    at pat.AddTreeGUI.GoButton1ActionPerformed(AddTreeGUI.java:218)
    at pat.AddTreeGUI.access$100(AddTreeGUI.java:13)
    at pat.AddTreeGUI$2.actionPerformed(AddTreeGUI.java:67)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
     ...
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: string data, right truncation;  table: TREES column: TREETYPE
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.enforceTypeLimits(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: string data, right truncation
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.types.CharacterType.convertToTypeLimits(Unknown Source)
    ... 53 more
```

however, it works when I input a real string eg

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, "Hello World");
```

How can this be done be acheved?

Answer (score 3):

> data exception: string data, right truncation;  table: TREES column: TREETYPE

The error message is telling you that the string value in the Java variable `TreeType` is longer than the maximum allowable length of a string in the column `TreeType` as defined in the `Trees` table. You'll either have to make the column wider or make your string shorter.